# Displaying a Span element Inline with Div element conditionally without CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have markup as shown below:

```
<span>First Name</span>
<span>Last Name</span>
<div>User Address</div>
<div>User Mobile Number</div>
<span>Edit Link</span>
```

When the markup is rendered on the page, I want last span ("Edit Link") to be displayed inline with previous element. "User Mobile Number" div is optional it may or not be present depending upon the user's choice. In short:

1) When `<div>User Mobile number</div>` is present "Edit Link" should come inline with it.
2) When `<div>User Mobile number</div>` is absent "Edit Link" should come inline with `<div>User Address</div>`.

Expected Output:

Case 1:
John Miller
St. JJ Street
+1-56565656 | Edit Link

Case 2:
John Miller
St. JJ Street | Edit Link

**Please let me know how to achieve this using CSS only**.Any help will be highly appreciated
**I am not allowed to use *CSS3* as it is not supported on lower version of IE**

Comment: That means only CSS is required.

Comment: Can you use CSS3 , I think we can fix it if you use CSS3

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

As you say that your `div` `User Mobile No` may or may not be present in that case we can make use of `CSS3 :nth-child` to make the second last `div's` `display` property to `display:inline-block;`.The `span` `Edit Link` is the last element so the second last element's `display` property should be `display:inline-block` to make sure that the `span` appears next to it.

I made a small change to your `HTML` I just wrapped your elements inside a `div` `container`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<span>First Name</span>
<span>Last Name</span>
<br/>

<div>User Address</div>
<div>User Mobile No</div>
<span>Edit Link</span>    
</div>
```

I also added a `<br/>` tag after `span` `Last Name` otherwise again the layout will be messed up.

**CSS:**

```
div#container div:nth-last-child(2)
{
display:inline-block;
}
```

This will select the second last element and apply style to it.

**[See Working Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/MDNV9/1/)**

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Making "User Mobile Number" div `display:inline-block` will make the "Edit Link" inline but what about "User Address" div, If I make it display inline "User Mobile Number" div will also come in same line.

Comment: @ManishKumar Ya got the issue , what will determine if the User Mob No  will be present or not.How are you adding it?

Comment: @ManishKumar Can you use jquery?

Comment: No, I can't use any for of Javascript. The whole markup is coming in a JSON through AJAX call. User fills a form then click on submit and data is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..but as I mentioned in my question I can't use CSS3 as it is not supported in Lower version of IE (7,8)

Comment: @ManishKumar You can upvote my answer if you think it is helpful.I think without javascript and css3 this can be a bit difficult.Thanks.